# Detect Visitor Browser view port size with Javascript and Save to a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

I almost sure that PHP can't detect the View port size of a browser right?

But since that, can someone teach me how can i do it with Javascript and then gather that size from a Javascript variable to a variable in PHP?

Regards

PS: Sorry if there is another post with the same question.

Comment: I can't help you with the answer to your question, but I can clarify that php can't detect view port size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the viewport size, you must use Javascript, yes.
For examples of code doing that (not always easy, there are differences between browsers), you can take a look at how JS Frameworks/Libraries determine that size (for instance, in prototype.js, there is a [getDimensions](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/document/viewport/getDimensions) function that does what you want) ; google will get you lots of results about that too ([this one](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/) is an example of those results)

Then, you must send that size to PHP. For that, two solutions :

- One is to use an Ajax request (sending the width and height as parameters)
- The other is to dynamically build an `<img>` tag, with an URL pointing to the PHP script, like `'http://.../size.php?w=WIDTH&h=HEIGHT'`

  - many statistic software (things like xiti / google analytics -- not sure if those ones do ^^ ) use that kind of method.

In the second case, the JS code could look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 100;
    var height = 80;
    var tag = document.createElement('img'); // Create the tag
    tag.src = 'http://tests/temp/viewport/size.php?';
    tag.src += 'w=' + width; // Pass the size
    tag.src += '&h=' + height;
    document.body.appendChild(tag); // Insert the tag into the page
</script>
```

And then, in size.php, you use $_GET['w'] and $_GET['h'].
Note : you will probably have to return some valid image data from size.php, to not get a "red cross" picture (a transparent gif, 1x1 in size, for instance, will do the trick)

Comment: Just as a side note : to avoid doing that request to size.php over and over again on every page of your site, you probably can store (in session for instance) the fact that the viewport's size is already known for a user, and that it is not necessary to recalculate/refetch it on next pages...

Comment: I've tried it.
And worked out. But the widht and height values they aper in the navigation bar.
There is a way they don't appear on it?

Comment: in the navigation bar ? using an img tag, the user should not see the URL called (except if he looks with something like firebug, or watch the requests made from the page). Even if the user sees the parameters, is it really that bad ?

Comment: No not really. Its just i've looking for this for some time, i've found some, but they all send the sizes to the nav bar.
I just asked if you now a way to hide it from the navbar. (using post method maybe?).

Comment: you can use POST when working with an img tag like this ; but you might, in this case, consider an Ajax-request (it will only work if your backend PHP script is on the same domain as the page, which is why statistic services don't use this method, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is how you can do it with jQuery:

```
var viewport_Width = $(window).width();  
var viewport_Height = $(window).height();
```

but this method has a bug in Opera. See here:

http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3046

use a workaround for Opera.

Then you can send it to the server (through POST or AJAX call) to save it in PHP.

Hope that helps.

Using a library like jQuery will avoid you many hassles and browser hacks.
Seriously consider using one, it solves a lot of server-side problems in the end.

Comment: Yes i will certainly use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

here's what I'd do (based on Pascal MARTIN's):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('img'); // Create the tag
    tag.src = 'http://path/to/file.php?';
    tag.src += 'w=' + document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    tag.src += '&h=' + document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(tag); // Insert the tag into the page
</script>
```

I have tested this on all major browsers (IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 2.x, Firefox 3.x, Opera 9.6x, Safari 3. and Chrome 2.x).

Comment: You are using some JS library here (looks like jQuery) ; but if KGTM's website doesn't use it, I think he shouldn't add it just for something like that, which can be done quite easily without a full JS Framework.
(I don't say JS Frameworks aren't great - they definitly are, and I almost never work on a wbesite without using one of them - but that, IMHO, you shouldn't include a whole Framework to do only a little thing)

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion. Corrected and based on your script.